# Why we can get the general solution by calculating the eigenvectors of Jacobian Matrix

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Assume $\dot{x} = f(x)$, we want to solve the autonomous ODE. One method is to find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ at critical points. Then, we can get the general solution of $x(t)$ according to some rules.

But, why we can relate the solution to the eigenvalues and eigenvector?

Answer (score 2):

Such a method is known as linearization. Solutions of the linearized equations are not solutions of the true ODE unless the ODE is linear. However, the solutions to the linearized equations about a critical point is topologically equivalent to the true solution in a neighborhood about the critical point by the [Hartman-Grobman theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hartman%E2%80%93Grobman_theorem).

Comment: I understand linearisation theorem but I am confused about the relation between the hessian matrix and general solution. Could you explain more? @whpowell96

Comment: Maybe you mean the Jacobian matrix and not the Hession? At a given critical point, the matrix $\partial f/\partial x$ is just a matrix and we can solve the resulting linear system, which is done using the eigendecomposition of the matrix, see https://www.math24.net/method-matrix-exponential/

Comment: The exact relationship between the linearized solution and the general solution is very technical and is given by the topological conjugacy mentioned in the HG article